# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection reset by peer (OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104), address = xxxxx, port = xxx

Tags: flutter, http

I'm trying to load messages every 2 second,  it works but it's returning Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection reset by peer (OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104), address = xxxxx, port = xxx, after a while. thinking the error is from my hosting but in my digital Ocean dashboard I have not exceeded 15% RAM, 3% CPU.

```
 void refresh() async {
    isOnline = userOnline(widget.user.lastVisit);
    const onesec = Duration(seconds: 2);
    timer = Timer.periodic(onesec, (timer) {
      loadMessages();
    });
  }


loadMessages() async {
    getMessages().then((messages) async {
      _messageController.add(messages);
      return messages;
    });
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> getMessages() async {
    List<dynamic> messages = [];
    ApiResponse response = await chatRepo.getChats(id: chatId!);
    if (response.error == null) {
      messages = response.data as List<dynamic>;
    } 
    return messages;
  }
 class ChatRepo {
  Future<ApiResponse> getChats({required int id}) async {
    ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
    try {
      final response =
          await http.get(Uri.parse(chatUrl + "/$apiKey/$id"), headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      });
      switch (response.statusCode) {
        case 200:
          apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body)['chats']
              .map((p) => ChatMessageTile.fromJson(p))
              .toList();
          apiResponse.data as List<dynamic>;
          break;
        case 401:
          apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
          break;
        default:
          apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
          break;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      apiResponse.error = serverError;
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
    return apiResponse;
  }

}
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Please suggest some workaround.